# Receiver type GTMSessionFetcher Service for instance message is a forward declaration

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-drive-api

I updated the pod GoogleAPIClientForREST/Drive from version:

- GoogleAPIClientForREST/Core (1.2.1):

  - GTMSessionFetcher (>= 1.1.7)
- GoogleAPIClientForREST/Drive (1.2.1):

  - GoogleAPIClientForREST/Core
  - GTMSessionFetcher (>= 1.1.7)

to the latest version:

- GoogleAPIClientForREST/Core (1.3.0):

  - GTMSessionFetcher (>= 1.1.7)
- GoogleAPIClientForREST/Drive (1.3.0):

  - GoogleAPIClientForREST/Core
  - GTMSessionFetcher (>= 1.1.7)

and since them I am getting following error:

> Receiver type GTMSessionFetcher Service for instance message is a
>   forward declaration

on following statement:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) GTMSessionFetcher *fetcher;
@property (nonatomic, retain) GTLRDriveService *googleDriveService;
...
self.fetcher = (GTMSessionFetcher *)[[[self googleDriveService] fetcherService] fetcherWithRequest:downloadRequest];
```

I tool a look at all google results regarding this error but none of them could help me get the problem. I also tried to use . instead of [], importing more headers, importing using <> instead of # etc. but nothing helped and I don't have idea what is the problem.

Comment: Is it possible you haven't loaded a 3rd party framework that is needed? If an import statement were missing I'd expect the compiler to tell you so.

Comment: I am importing #import "GTMSessionFetcher.h" and #import "GTLRDrive.h" so I would not not what else, sadly the error message is not helpfull at all

Comment: I usually use Carthage not pods, and this sounds like a pods issue. Are you sure you clicked on the white workspace file and not the blue project file to open the project in Xcode?